# javascript, promises, how to access variable this inside a then scope

Tags: javascript, promise, angular-promise

I want to be able to call a function inside the *.then* scope, and for that I use the *this.foo()* manner. But if I do this inside the *.then* I get an error, since *this* appears to be lost. What can I do?

In this code, this would be equivalent to have the same output for the object *this*

```
console.log(this)
one().then(function() {
  console.log(this)
})

function one() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  deferred.resolve()
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

This neither seems to work

```
console.log(this)
var a = this;
one().then(function(a) {
  console.log(a)
})
```

Comment: If you remove the `a` argument from `one().then(function(a) {` so that it's `one().then(function() {`, then that will give you the result you want.

Comment: Yes, I was testing it just when I've seen your answer. You're totally right! I'll mark it as an answer if you post it as an answer

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Your second code example is the right way to go. Because the scope changes in the new function, `this` changes too, so you're right to make a reference to `this` outside of the function.

The reason it failed is because the function is using `a` that you passed into the function rather than the global `a` you defined outside it.

In other words:

```
var a = this;

one().then(function () {
  console.log(a)
});
```

Update: use an arrow function - they borrow the context (`this`) from their outer scope.

```js
function two() {
  console.log('Done');
}

one().then(() => {
  this.two();
});

function one() {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => res(), 2000);
  });
}
```

Comment: or ... `one().then(function () {
  console.log(this)
}.bind(this))` _usual disclaimer that internet exploder before 9 is a waste of disk space and should never be relied on to do anything other than display static web pages_

Comment: Yeah, @JaromandaX, I was just looking over the edit someone made to the answer and the code didn't look right. Yours looks accurate.

Comment: yours is right, and probably easier to use in many cases, you know just by looking where you put `var a = this` exactly what `a/this` will be - whereas, using bind, it may not be exactly what you expect or want for that matter :p

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great example.