# Changes to a property in a service not triggering a change

Tags: angular-services, angularjs

I have the following `UserService` where I'm simply having a property within the instance that determines whether the user `isAuthenticated`. For some reason, even though the value is being changes by setting `this.isAuthenticated` to various value, on `logout` and some other methods, that change is not being caught by Angular. I even tried doing a manual `$digest` and `$apply` but still no luck.

```
export default class UserService {

  constructor($http, $state, AppConstants, JWTService) {
    'ngInject';

    this.$http = $http;
    this.$state = $state;

    this.isAuthenticated = false;
  }


  logout() {
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
    this.$state.go('login', null, { reload: true });
  }

  verify() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      // if a user exists, then resolve
      if (this.isAuthenticated) {
        return resolve(true);
      }

      this.$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `${this.AppConstants.api}/verify`
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
        return resolve(true);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.isAuthenticated = false;
        return resolve(false);
      });
    });
  }

}
```

The code works and when I login the first time, I set the `this.isAuthenticated` to true and the `this.verify` works by posting. However, when I `logout`, even though the `this.isAuthenticatd` is so to `false`, the condition `if (this.isAuthenticated)` is still `true` when `this.verify` is called again.

Comment: This appears to be an Angular v1 question? If so, please update your tags. `angular` is for Angular v2+, `angularjs` is for angular 1. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the tags.

Answer (score 0):

"this" is not what you think it is inside your .then() function.  The scope has changed.  This scenario is common and just something you have to constantly keep in mind when working in javascript.  Here is just one example of what you can do about it:

[javascript promises and "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547735/javascript-promises-how-to-access-variable-this-inside-a-then-scope)

Comment: I know what the `this` is, as the context remains the same, given we're using the fat arrow syntax. I've already tested that to ensure we're in the same context.